# Get the closest 1000's number to a random number

Tags: javascript

So I have a number that gets randomly generated (between 1000-12000). Now, if the number is for example `6859` then, it should get the number `859`. But that number is randomized. I tried this:

```
var number = 6589;
var aaa = 1000;
var b = 0;
if (number < aaa) {
<!-- Do something -->
} else if (number < aaa*2) {
  var b = number-aaa;
} else if (number < aaa*3) {
  var b = number-aaa*2;
} else if (number < aaa*4) {
  var b = number-aaa*3;
}
```

And so on, so on.. 
This isn't really good-coded. As, I think it should be easier to do this. Could anyone help? (Sorry, Im a js noob)

Comment: Wouldn't `number % aaa` yield your desired result?

Comment: what is `<!-- Do something -->` doing?

Comment: What does `number % aaa` do? @haim770

Comment: @NinaScholz print something in console

Comment: @AaronJonk it's the *modulus* operator, giving the remainder after dividing by 1000.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're looking for the [*remainder operator*](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-applying-the-mod-operator), `%`. It returns the remainder of a division operation:

```js
console.log(6859 % 1000); // 859
```

(This is also sometimes called the *modulo* or *modulus operator*, but remainder and the standard forms of modulo are slightly different when dealing with a divisor and dividend of differing signs. Or something like that, I don't have much math learnin'. :-) The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) covers some of it; there's also the page on [modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic).)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the modulus operator.

```js
var number = 6589;
var aaa = 1000;
var b = number % aaa;

console.log(b);
```